# Spring Application failed to start

Tags: java, mysql, spring, repository

iam beginner with spring and want to do so sample project .. i have a database which i want to connect to it .. i used annotaions like AutoWired & service .. But there is problem i can't solve

RegisterationController *in Controller Package* which have a service i want to call :

```js
@RestController
public class RigesterationController {
 @Autowired
 private DataManagment dm =new DataManagment() ;
 
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8060")
 @GetMapping("/SignUp/{email}/{UName}/{Pass}/{gender}/{UserType}")
 @ResponseBody
 public void SignUp(@PathVariable String email , @PathVariable String UName , 
        @PathVariable String Pass , @PathVariable char gender , @PathVariable String UserType )
 {  
  boolean valid = dm.Validate(email , Pass ) ; // validate email & Pass
  if (valid)
  {
   if (UserType.equals("s"))
   {
    StudentAccount studentaccount = new StudentAccount(email , Pass , UName , gender) ;
    dm.add(studentaccount) ;
    System.out.println("Account Created Successfully"  );
   }
  }
  else 
  { 
   System.out.println("Invalid Data, Please Try Again" );
  }
  
  }
```

DataManagement Class *in first Package* :

```js
@Service
public class DataManagment {
 
 @Autowired
 private StudentAccountRepository StudentAccount1 ;
 
  public boolean Validate (String email , String Pass )
 {
  
  if(!email.contains("@") || email.contains(" ") || (Pass.length()<8) || !email.contains(".com") )
   return false;
  else
   return true;
 }
  
 public void add(StudentAccount studentaccount2) {
  StudentAccount1.save(studentaccount2) ;
 }
```

StudentAccountRepository *in first Package*:

```js
package first;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface StudentAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentAccount,String > {

}
```

Student Account *in first Package* .. which refer to the table in database :

```js
package first;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="studentaccount")
public class StudentAccount  {
 @Id
 private String email;
 private String password;
 private String name ;
 private char gender;
 
 public StudentAccount(String email, String password , String name , char gender ) {
  super();
  this.email = email;
  this.password = password;
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  
 }
 
 public StudentAccount() {
  super();
  this.email = "";
  this.password = "";
  this.name = "";
  this.gender = ' ';
 }

 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public char getGender() {
  return gender;
 }

 public void setGender(char gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
 }

}
```

MainController Class

```js
package controller;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainController {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args);
 }
}
```

now i have this Error :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field dm in controller.RigesterationController required a bean of type 'first.DataManagment' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'first.DataManagment' in your configuration.

Comment: Can you show your main class?

Comment: Check Post .. it is edited Now

Answer (score 0):

if you use `@Autowired` on `private DataManagment` you can't use `new` because that way Spring is unable to autowire it because it doesn't know anything about your new object. `@Autowired` as name suggests is used by Spring to auto find something that already exists. Besides if you're trying to inject by constructor it should be done like this

```
private DataManagement dm;

@Autowired
public RigesterationController(DataManagment dm)
{
   this.dm = dm;
}
```

and for field injection just type

```
@Autowired
private DataManagement dm;
```

Comment: I don't Understand the edited part .. do you mean replace service annotaion by Component annotaion ..
i wrote as you said and made constructor but 
there is another error :-   
Parameter 0 of constructor in controller.RigesterationController required a bean of type 'first.DataManagment' that could not be found.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that `@Service` annotation. Did you have a look at these?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333147/autowired-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547665/autowired-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency-at-least-1-bean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961275/no-matching-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency

Comment: I looked At these .. But I think these are for another problems